# Convert preformatted string to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

How can i easily transform this string to vector in javascript?

`"'id': '123', 'name': 'Bob', 'revenue': '51.1'"`

Many thnks

Comment: So before we go off the deep end, are you aware that arrays only have numerical indexes?  So, an array will not let you index by `id` or `name` or `revenue`.  Only objects will.  So with that in mind, what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: What happens if any of those values contain apostrophes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're thinking of an associative array, which JavaScript does not support. However, objects in JavaScript can *almost* be thought of as associative arrays since an object is really just a bucket to hold key/value pairs. With that being said below is some code that will parse your string and create an object literal. There is a second example in the code that will, instead, store each key/value pair as a string in an array:

```js
//The original string
var s = "'id': '123', 'name': 'Bob', 'revenue': '51.1'";

//Turn the string into a structured object
var f = s.split(',').map(s => {
  var kv = s.split(':');
  var k = kv[0].trim();
  var v = kv[1].trim();
  return {
    k,
    v
  };
});

//Use reduce to compose into a larger object
var o = f.reduce((accum, el) => {
  var {
    k,
    v
  } = el;
  accum[k.replace(/'/gi, '')] = v;
  return accum;
}, {});
console.log(o);

//Or keep each item as a string in an array
var a = f.reduce((accum, el) => {
  var {
    k,
    v
  } = el;
  accum.push(`${k.replace(/'/gi, '')}:${v}`);
  return accum;
}, []);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Or simply, ``const convert = s => JSON.parse(`{${s.replace(/'/g, '"')}}`)``